# Tomcat use DefaultServlet for static content in external directory

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

I have a simple web app that allows the user to upload and access files. When the user accesses an uploaded file, the server needs to support all of the header types such as Accept-Ranges so that partial-content responses can be made on large media files. The DefaultServlet (in Tomcat) handles everything well in its [serveResource()](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/servlets/DefaultServlet.html#serveResource(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,%20javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse,%20boolean)) method called by doGet(), so I would like to use the DefaultServlet for the uploaded files. This is easy enough in normal circumstances since it is the DEFAULT servlet, but unfortunately for my case, I am unable to find a way to use the default servlet.

In order to prevent the uploaded files from being deleted when the webapp is redeployed, I need to store them outside of the webapp directory. 
These files should only be accessible to the user that uploaded them, so I created a javax.servlet.Filter to handle resource access authorization. I know that if I add a new context in server.xml for the external resource directory, they will be accessible, and the DefaultServlet will be used.

```
<Context docBase="/path/to/resources" path="/resource" />
```

But I do not want to do that because then I am required to invasively modify server.xml which is not recommended ([for reasons](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html#Defining_a_context)), and when a context exists for the /resource path, my filter for that url-mapping will not be invoked.  So I do not think creating a new context is a good solution.

The only other solution I can think of would be to create a servlet for all requests at '/resource/*' which extends DefaultServlet, and somehow override functionality that would instead get the requested file at its actual external location rather than returning 404 on the non-existent resource in the webapp.
However, I have not been able to find an easy way to convert the DefaultServlet into one that can fetch files external to the webapp directory. Maybe there is a way?

How would I go about handling this?

Comment: What is your Tomcat version?

Comment: I am running Tomcat v7.0.42

Comment: Have you considered [this](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html#Virtual_webapp)?

Answer (score 0):

*Not an answer*

> In order to prevent the uploaded files from being deleted when the
>   webapp is redeployed

It means you are re-deploying your stuffs wrong(in a very bad manner), probably using war files, or worse(worst) tomcat manager.

> I know that if I add a new context in server.xml for the external
>   resource directory, they will be accessible, and the DefaultServlet
>   will be used.

You are right, but you are wrong about having another context, it's not necessary.

Solutions:

Dear [Michael-O](https://stackoverflow.com/users/696632/michael-o) specified the easiest and probably best answer.

You may also implement something like `DefaultServlet` too, sometimes(not for your case) it's better to implement things from zer0 rather than configuring and maintaining many too much complex stuffs.